# Can not create workspace for Liferay 7.2-rc2

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am trying to create a workspace for 7.2-rc2 but fail to do so.

I created a normal workspace for 7.1 in Liferay Developer Studio (version 3.5.0) since there is no support for 7.2 yet. To test if I can run code correctly I created a new mvc-portlet in Developer Studio.

I then set `liferay.workspace.target.platform.version=7.2.0` in `gradle.properties`. Gradle is not able to build my module:

> 15:16:04: Executing task 'deploy'...
>
> Task :wrapper
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
>   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
>   See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
>   1 actionable task: 1 executed
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not determine the dependencies of task ':modules:test:buildCSS'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':modules:test:detachedConfiguration1'.
>     Could not find com.liferay.portal:release.portal.bom:7.2.0.
>      Searched in the following locations:
>
>   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom/7.2.0/release.portal.bom-7.2.0.pom
>   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom/7.2.0/release.portal.bom-7.2.0.pom
>   - https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom/7.2.0/release.portal.bom-7.2.0.pom
>   - https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom/7.2.0/release.portal.bom-7.2.0.pom
>       Required by:
>        project :modules:test
>       Could not find com.liferay.portal:release.portal.bom.compile.only:7.2.0.
>       Searched in the following locations:
>   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom.compile.only/7.2.0/release.portal.bom.compile.only-7.2.0.pom
>   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom.compile.only/7.2.0/release.portal.bom.compile.only-7.2.0.pom
>   - https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom.compile.only/7.2.0/release.portal.bom.compile.only-7.2.0.pom
>   - https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom.compile.only/7.2.0/release.portal.bom.compile.only-7.2.0.pom
>       Required by:
>        project :modules:test
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
>   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
>   See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s
>   Could not find com.liferay.portal:release.portal.bom:7.2.0.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>     - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom/7.2.0/release.portal.bom-7.2.0.pom
>     - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom/7.2.0/release.portal.bom-7.2.0.pom
>     - https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom/7.2.0/release.portal.bom-7.2.0.pom
>     - https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom/7.2.0/release.portal.bom-7.2.0.pom
>   Required by:
>       project :modules:test
>   15:16:07: Task execution finished 'deploy'.

I do not think the deprecation warning is at fault.

Which settings do I actually have to set to get all the necessary dependencies for 7.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that 7.2.0-rc2 or rc3 have not been uploaded into the apache maven central repository yet. I'm also looking for a maven repository that has these artifacts.

Comment: This is the correct answer AFAIK. I was told that the plan was to release a 7.2 compatible Liferay Developer Studio when 7.2 officially releases as a stable release

Answer (score 1):

By updating existing eclipse, you can build 7.2 plugin. Use below URL from liferay to update eclipse.

[Install Liferay IDE](https://liferay.dev/project/-/asset_publisher/TyF2HQPLV1b5/content/ide-installation-instructions)